# Two Update Statements with One Button Click

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am using a SQL data adapter in a C# windows form and I am trying to run two update statements on two separate databases with one button click using the same string.  I keep getting an exception error and I think that the second update statement is trying to use the connection for the first update statement but I can't figure it out.  Anybody have any ideas?

```
                string resendacct = textBox_resendVisit.Text.Trim();

                SqlConnection CONN1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERVER1.domain.company.org; Initial Catalog=db1; User ID=username; Password=password    ;Trusted_Connection=False");

                //OPEN SQL CONNECTION
                CONN1.Open();

                //CREATE NEW SQLCOMMAND
                SqlCommand cmd = CONN1.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText =
                 "UPDATE PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time  " +
                     "SET PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time.sent_datetime = null  " +
                 "FROM PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time  " +
                 "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity  " +
                 "ON PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity.custidentity = PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time.custidentity  " +
                 "WHERE PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity.account = @resendtimes";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resendtimes", resendacct);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int noRows;

                noRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                //THIS COMMAND RESENDS THE DATABASE2 REPORTS!//

                SqlConnection CONN2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERV2.domain.company.org; Initial Catalog=db2; Integrated Security=TRUE");

                //OPEN SQL CONNECTION
                CONN2.Open();

                //CREATE NEW SQL COMMAND
                SqlCommand cmd1 = CONN2.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time  " +
                        "SET PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time.timedone = null  " +
                    "FROM PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time  " +
                    "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity  " +
                    "ON PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity.id = PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time.custencounter_id  " +
                    "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter  " +
                    "ON PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter.id = PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity.custencounter_id  " +
                    "WHERE PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter.accountnumber = @resendtimes";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resendtimes", resendacct);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int noRows1;

                noRows1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //CLOSE SQLCONNECTIONS
                CONN1.Close();
                CONN2.Close();
```

Comment: `...I keep getting an exception error`, uh, I think that would be important for us to see to help yes?

Comment: You are creating a new command for `CONN2`, but you are setting command text on the first command, not the one you just created. Change `cmd.CommandText` to `cmd1.CommandText` after you create a second connection.

Comment: It's also good practice to close a connection when you are done with it. If you would have closed `CONN1` after you executed the first command, then you would have gotten a better error that would have made it easier to understand what the problem was.

Comment: Yep I got it now, I can't believe that I missed that. What a dumb mistake.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second command is being assigned to the first command variable you created. That command is using the first connection. Check your cmd and cmd1. I think your second sql statement should be assigned to cmd1 instead of cmd.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that i missed that.  I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes because I have been staring at this for two hours now.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can read your answer below. But before that i must say that you should your connection like

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection())
{
   //your code here.
}
```

in your second command you are doing all the operation on your `cmd` whereas they should be on `cmd1`. You should code like this.

```
using (SqlConnection CONN1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERVER1.domain.company.org; Initial Catalog=db1; User ID=username; Password=password    ;Trusted_Connection=False"))
        {
            //OPEN SQL CONNECTION
            CONN1.Open();

            //CREATE NEW SQLCOMMAND
            using (SqlCommand cmd = CONN1.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText =
                 "UPDATE PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time  " +
                     "SET PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time.sent_datetime = null  " +
                 "FROM PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time  " +
                 "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity  " +
                 "ON PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity.custidentity = PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.date_time.custidentity  " +
                 "WHERE PRODUCTIONDB1.dbo.useridentity.account = @resendtimes";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resendtimes", resendacct);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int noRows;

                noRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        //THIS COMMAND RESENDS THE DATABASE2 REPORTS!//

        using (SqlConnection CONN2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBSERV2.domain.company.org; Initial Catalog=db2; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
        {
            //OPEN SQL CONNECTION
            CONN2.Open();

            //CREATE NEW SQL COMMAND
            using (SqlCommand cmd1 = CONN2.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd1.CommandText =
                    "UPDATE PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time  " +
                        "SET PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time.timedone = null  " +
                    "FROM PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time  " +
                    "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity  " +
                    "ON PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity.id = PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.date_time.custencounter_id  " +
                    "INNER JOIN PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter  " +
                    "ON PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter.id = PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custidentity.custencounter_id  " +
                    "WHERE PRODUCTIONDB2.dbo.custencounter.accountnumber = @resendtimes";
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resendtimes", resendacct);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int noRows1;

                noRows1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```